# Bake in function definition to prevent overloading in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, overriding

```
// Change the following function:
function sayHello(name) {
  return "Hello " + name;
}

// Not possible to change the code below
console.log(sayHello("John"));

function sayHello(name) {
  return "Hola " + name;
}
```

The output of the following code will be `Hola John`.

Is it possible to modify the first definition of the function `sayHello` so that the output would be `Hello John`? Perhaps there is a way to modify the function in a way that would 'inline' the definition in the place where it is called before it gets overridden later...?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer to this is no. The second definition of `sayHello` will always overwrite the first due to hoisting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

function sayHello declares it at first pass. then at second pass, you can "rebind/overwrite" definition of sayHello

```
// Change the following function:
sayHello = function(name) {
  return "Hello " + name;
}

// Not possible to change the code below
console.log(sayHello("John"));

function sayHello(name) {
  return "Hola " + name;
}
```

Comment: 1. You should be using `var`

Comment: 2. The function can't be redefined this way

Comment: 1. why should be var used? be it there or not, purpose is to mask 'hola function', so might as well make it global
2. console.log outputs hello, which is the expected behaviour, only a problem of vocabulary there

Comment: That's what I was looking for, thanks! Can you explain why is that working?

Comment: when the js engine reads your js, it firsts look for function xx, and var xx, whatever their content/value (the variable refered by var would be at this point automatically set to undefined), it declares them in your environnment, so you can access them later. Then when your js engine is running, you can associate a value to those name.
So specifically, you can set a value to sayHello.

In this case, when accessing sayHello afterwards, you will get your setted value instead of the content which should have been run (sayHola if you had'n't setted an other value)